# Split multiple comma seperated to unique rows in excel

Tags: excel, vba

i am new to vba, i have a requirement in one of the report i need to generate

for example

```
A     B     C    D    E
R1 1,2,3 A,B,C Q,W,E  1
```

Once I run a macro it should show like below:

```
R1 1 A Q 1
R1 2 B W 1
R1 3 C E 1
```

this is a just a sample data, my excel has A - AO columns and almost 10,000 records

Please advice

Comment: You can try Power Query in Excel 2010 and above https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Split-column-not-into-seperate-columns-but-in-rows/td-p/11194

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this without external tools is to use the `Split` function, which retuns an array of strings.

You could split each column and then add rows based on the same index, if that is what you need, or add rows based on all possible combinations.